# stopping a subprocess.call loop in my python code

Tags: python, subprocess

```
def raspi_connecter():
    print("Below is the output from the shell script in terminal")
    subprocess.call('ssh dev@X.0.0.X', shell=True)
```

That code opens my raspi in my GUI program, however when i go to click the other buttons on my window (execute commands, update, import file) my mac has the rainbow wheel of death. I assume it is because it is caught in an open loop but maybe am wrong?

Would Popen be better than .call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Popen should be the sulotion. Look in the documentation for more info
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful to break the loop

Comment: could you pls check the question as answered.. Thanks